# How can I use amber framework (objective-c framework) to performSelectorOnMainThread?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to send multi-arguments to `performSelectorOnMainThread` method, but it can send only one parameter. I search for the approach  and found amber framework can do this, but I can't see any api or the document. I don't know how to use it. Any guys here can help me please?

Comment: you can wrap multiple args into a dictionary for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to put your data in an `NSDictionary` and pass the dictionary as the sole parameter to the method. You will notice that this is what is often done in Cocoa, see for instance the notification objects.

If you feel like it, you can also define a class with custom properties for your purpose, but it is probably not worth it.